# incomplete last line when writing to a file in java

Tags: java-io, ubuntu-18.04

I am writing to a file /etc/cron.d/myscript and using FileWriter/PrintWriter and flushing it before closing the writer but when I read the file using a vi editor , I get the status as incomplete last line.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("/etc/cron.d/myscript"))
fw.write("@reboot username scriptpath");
fw.flush();
fw.close();
```

How can i avoid this , as it giving me problems in executing my cron job.

I've tried using PrintWriter as well but doesn't work.

I'm using java8 on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

```
fw.write("@reboot username scriptpath"+"\n");
```

Solved the issue